# PHP Add file extension on to url

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP image uploader, code is below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please view all of the allowed   extensions before uploading.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }               

    $file_name = mt_rand(100000000,999999999); 

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">swal({ title: 'Success!',   html:  'Your image has been uploaded <a href=\"/images/$file_name\">here</a> '   });</script>";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

I recently added this script

```
$file_name = mt_rand(100000000,999999999);
```

So each image will have it's own unique url, the problem is there is no .jpg, .png/file extension at the end of the image. When I take an image's link and add a .jpg at the end, it will give me a 404 error. (And I know the file is a jpg)

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the URL will look like this www.websitehere/com/images/324686653

But when I add the extension to the end like this..

www.websitehere/com/images/324686653.png it will give me a 404

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: What's wrong with appending the extension to `$file_name` before moving the file?

Comment: Did you try adding your extension to the file name?
Like:
  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name.".".$file_ext);
Or something like that.....

Comment: @Armin Yes I have tried that, that throws a 404 at me as well.

Comment: If your extension is right, I don't see why this wouldn't work. Can you var_dump/echo this part $file_tmp,"images/".$file_name.".".$file_ext ?
You should find uploaded image, and check if extension is added...

Comment: @Armin Just tried it again, it adds the extension to the url, but it gets a 404 because the file is being saved as random numbers

Comment: @TheRealSpector I am aware of that. In fact I think I had a similar problem few years ago. This is how I believe I solved it. move_uploaded_file() method should save file with the name you provided(hopefully), so when you add extension at the end of a file it will  be there. Did you double-check it is the right extension? If it's saved as jpeg maybe you're trying to load .jpg, or something like that. Best way is to drag your image to the browser(if it's local image), and check for full name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Armin for helping me answer this...

So this is what I did, I added this:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name.".".$file_ext);
```

And then added this:

```
<a href=\"/images/$file_name.$file_ext\">here</a>
```

Hope this helps!